# Using Jquery's .each() function makes the web page lag on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on a `span` or `div` element the audio is played. The function also contains `.each()` to prevent the audios from overlapping each other, that is, when a user clicks a word, the audio is played and when a user clicks on another word, the current audio stops playing and the new audio is played.

The problem is, I have over a thousand `span` or `div` elements on some of my pages and while the web page works perfectly on computers, it lags horribly on mobile/smaller devices.

The web pages takes a maximum of 2 seconds to load on computers but takes 15-20 seconds on mobile/smaller devices. I've already found the culprit to be this `.each()` function because I guess it loops through the whole 1000+ elements on the page when it loads and the mobile devices are unable to take this load.

I'm looking for a solution to this problem because if I remove the `.each()` function, the page loads quickly on mobile devices but then the audio overlapping issue comes up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<span data-audio-url="hello.mp3">Hello</span>
<span data-audio-url="hello.mp3">Hello</span>
<span data-audio-url="hello.mp3">Hello</span>    
<div data-audio-url="hello.mp3">Hello</div>
```

```js
$("span, div").each(function(event) { 
  $(this).data('audio-object', new Audio()); 
}).on('click', function (event, e) {
  var e = event || window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;

  if (e.stopPropagation) 
    e.stopPropagation();

  var audio_url = $(this).attr('data-audio-url');

  $("span, div").each(function() {
    var audio = $(this).data('audio-object');
    if (audio.src) {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }    
  });

  var clickedAudio = $(this).data('audio-object');
  if (!clickedAudio.src) { 
    clickedAudio.src = audio_url; 
  }    
  clickedAudio.play();
});
```

Comment: If you only want to play one MP3 at a time you would only need one `Audio()` object.

Comment: The larger question is why you have thousands of spans in the page in the first place? It sounds like you should be using searching/paging/filtering to reduce the working set

Comment: It's probably not the `.each` itself but making the Audio instances for each span, which will end up with 1000+ objects in memory

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your solution is not applicable in my case sorry...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware how can I do that? Any examples?

Comment: @VLAZ That's exactly the issue like I said. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because you first needlessly loop through every selected element and then add an `audio` element in to jQuery's `data` cache for that element. Then within the click handler itself you again loop through all the elements and pause the `audio` elements in their `data`. These two loops are very costly in terms of performance.

To simplify this just use a single `audio` element in the DOM when the page loads and change its `src` when the relevant element is clicked. Using this method you don't need either of the loops.

As suggested in the comments by @LieRyan, you could then avoid the implicit loop through the elements to bind all the event handlers by using a single delegated event handler on the container of all the `span` and `div` elements. Try this:

```js
var audio = $('#player')[0];

$('#container').on('click', 'span, div', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var audio_url = $(this).data('audio-url');
  audio.src = audio_url;
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <span data-audio-url="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga">Hello</span>
  <span data-audio-url="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sound/sound_90.mp3">Hello</span>
  <div data-audio-url="http://media.w3.org/2010/11/rrs006.oga">Hello</div>
</div>

<audio id="player"></audio>
```

Note that `preventDefault()` isn't needed here, as `span` and `div` elements have no default click behaviour to be prevented.

Also note that having thousands of elements listing samples sounds like overkill. I'd strongly suggest you implement paging, searching and/or filtering to make it much easier for your users to navigate.

Comment: This will still loop through every elements on startup, which probably shouldn't be a major issue. But if you have a lot of span and divs and want to eliminate that, you would want to use event delegation, so the Click listener registration looks like so: `$("#container").on('click', "span, div", function ...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory, your solution worked perfectly! And I know having thousands of elements on the screen at the same time isn't really a good idea but I'm working on it. Thanks again! I really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: @LieRyan thanks for your comment but again, what exactly will your solution do? Rory's solution works perfectly and I don't see any looping there. However I'm always open to improve my code.

Comment: @MarwanAnsari It's hard to explain in a comment section, but regular event attachment will attach one listener for every matched element. If you have a thousand span in the page, jQuery have to loop through one thousand elements and attach a listener to every single element and the browser have to keep track of one thousand event listeners objects. Event delegation attach only one event listener on a container (usually only one container for the entire page) and relies on event propagation to capture events from child elements. To expand more: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @LieRyan all of the thousands elements are in a single container. So I suppose your solution won't work for me?

Comment: That's the perfect scenario :) In that case change the selector to `$('#yourContainer').on('click', 'span, div', function(e) { ...`

Comment: @MarwanAnsari You can delegate the event to `$("body")` if you want to capture absolutely every span and div in the page. Please read the page I have linked for more explanation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan would you suggest using Lie's solution with yours? Will it improve performance in any way?

Comment: I would suggest it yes, in fact I've edited the answer above to include their suggestion. In reality the differences won't be more than a few milliseconds, even with a thousand elements in the DOM, but it's free performance.